coupled discrete dynamical system -- bifurcation analysis
Suppose you have the following coupled discrete dynamical system:
\begin{align*}
e_{k+1}&=e_k - 2~\alpha~e_k~\lambda^2~\alpha_k^2 + \alpha^2~e_k^2~\lambda^3 \alpha_k^3\\
\alpha_{k+1}&= \alpha_k(1 - 2~\alpha~\lambda~e_k),
\end{align*}
where $\lambda > 0$ is a fixed constant and $\alpha>0$ is parameter (corresponding to the step-size) which can be set to make the system converge into some trajectory.
I want to understand the convergence of this system (i.e., the trajectory of $e_k$ and/or $d_k$ for various ranges of $\alpha$ parameter via a bifurcation analysis. For e.g. if we sweep $\alpha$ from sufficiently small values to slightly large value to very large values, do we observe periodic dynamics and chaotic dynamics, etc?
Any leads or references will be much appreciated.
